# SpringBootTest: Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when calling CRUD repository in @component test file

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am a beginner in testing and now I have a problem that I cannot overcome.

```
@SpringBootTest
ExampleMakerSpec extends Specification {

@Autowired @Subject ExampleMaker exampleMaker
@Autowired 
ExampleRepository exampleRepository

def EXAMPLE_VARIABLE = "Example"

@Transactional
def "example() trying to do somehthing" () {      
    when: "trying to make some examples"
        Examples examples = exampleMaker.createExamples(examples)

    then: "get examples sizes and saves them to database"
        examples.size == 7
```

My Example maker looks like that:

```
@Component
public class ExampleMaker {

    @Autowired
    ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    public void createExamples() {
        exampleRepository.save(Examples);

    }


}
```

And CRUD repository:

```
@Repository
public interface exampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, Long> {

}
```

but I am always getting

java.lang.NullPointerException at line exampleRepository.save(Examples).

So for some reason the tests cannot find the repository. I need assistance here to understand what is missing.

Comment: You forgot `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Comment: Is it compulsory for testing when using groovy?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications. Not sure why using Groovy would change anything.

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You need to autowire the exampleRepository in your test class. So when your test class `ExampleMakerSpec` is created, Spring looks for and injects `ExampleRepository`